# Search regex on a specific field using awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

In awk I can search a field for a value like:

```
$ echo -e "aa,bb,cc\ndd,eaae,ff" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}; $2=="eaae" {print $0};'
aa,bb,cc
dd,eaae,ff
```

And I can search by regular expressions like

```
$ echo -e "aa,bb,cc\ndd,eaae,ff" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}; /[a]{2}/ {print $0};'
aa,bb,cc
dd,eaae,ff
```

Can I force the awk to apply the regexp search to a specific field ? I'm looking for something like

```
$ echo -e "aa,bb,cc\ndd,eaae,ff" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}; $2==/[a]{2}/ {print $0};'
```

expecting result:

```
dd,eaae,ff
```

Anyone know how to do it using awk?

Accepted response - Operator "~" (thanks to hek2mgl):

```
$ echo -e "aa,bb,cc\ndd,eaae,ff" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";}; $2 ~ /[a]{2}/ {print $0};'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use :

```
$2 ~ /REGEX/ {ACTION}
```

If the regex should apply to the second field (for example) only.

---

In your case this would lead to:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^[a]{2}$/' <<< "aa,bb,cc\ndd,eaae,ff"
```

You may wonder why I've just used the regex in the awk program and no `print`. This is because your action is `print $0` - printing the current line - which is the default action in awk.